# Testing a wicket page part by part

Tags: testing, wicket

I have a wicket class like so:

```java
public class MyReport extends AbstractReport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public MyReport(PageParameters parameters) throws ParseException {
        super(parameters);
        try {

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing from/to date");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();
        setPageHeader();
    }

    protected void setPageHeader() {
        add(new TaxHeader("pageHeader")); //TaxHeader extends Panel

    }

    protected void setPageFooter(CustomerDTO customerInfoForFooter) {
       //TO BE ADDED

     }

}
```

The HTML markup is like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<wicket:head>
    <title><wicket:message key="k4.title">Title</wicket:message></title>
    <meta name="author" content="abc" />

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <wicket:link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general.css" media="all" />
    </wicket:link>
</wicket:head> 

<BODY>
    <div id="pageHeader" class="pageHeader" wicket:id="pageHeader" >HEADER</div>
       <div id="pageFooter" class="pageFooter" wicket:id="pageFooter" >FOOTER</div>


   </BODY>
   </html>
```

The test class is like this

```java
public class ReportTest extends WicketTestBase {

@Test
public void reportShouldRenderCorrectly() {
    tester.startPage(MyReport.class, new PageParamenters());
    tester.assertRenderedPage(MyReport.class);
}

}
```

What I would like is to go test driven with building the page and testing it. By that I mean I want to test the methods `setPageHeader()` and `setPageFooter()` separately of each other. Something like

```java
@Test
public void pageHeaderShouldRenderCorrectly()
```

This is not possible however, because wicket will not load the page and complain that the 'pageFooter' wicket tag has not been set with a component. 
As you can imagine, for a complex HTML page with a lot of wicket references, it would mean that all of them are fulfilled before the above test can be run.

Is there a way to circumvent this? Note that I don't want to end up testing the component (namely the `TaxHeader` class in this case). What I want is to be testing the rendering of wicket.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to your question but might help anyway...

The code as it is isn't very testable as you found out by yourself. To make it more testable you'd have to get rid of the tight coupling in your methods. Changing the `setPageHeader` method to something like this

```
protected void setPageHeader(Component parent) {
    parent.add(new TaxHeader("pageHeader")); //TaxHeader extends Panel
}
```

would improve this but then it would belong to the domain of your `TaxHeader` class and should be moved there, resulting in surprising (and therefore badly readable) codeflow.

On the other hand... Ask yourself if you really have to test this method. Sure 100% code coverage looks great but is seldom worth the effort and even rarer meaningful in any way. This method does two things.

- It calls wicket's `add`-method, the functionality of which could be taken for granted (and testing it would be the job of the wicket-developers). The usage is checked by the compiler and the results can be checked by your page-rendering-test
- It calls a constructor, that can and should be tested but not in the context of the page test. It deserves a test of it's own which can easily be done by using the startComponentInPage-method of WicketTester.

Comment: Well I understand the fact that TaxHeader as a component can be tested separately on its own. But how do I test the assertion "I have written code to add "pageheader" . 
It seems a bit counterintuitive to me while developing Wicket pages as a 'newbie'. There seems to be testing support in the framework but it seems like I am unable to write atomic tests that will pass before and after the whole page is complete.

Comment: As wicket doesn't work with interfaces you can't simply use a mock object to test this, but you can create a mock Component (most likely a WebPage) that contains the minimal markup needed and use this as a parameter for setPageHeader. In Wickettester you can then assert that the component at path "pageHeader" is of type TaxHeader, verfying your assertion.